# Proving a language with $(ab)^n$ is not regular with pumping lemma?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I have been working to understand the pumping lemma better, but I am quite stuck at proving these two languages is not regular:

\begin{align}
L_1 &= \{(ab)^n c^m \mid n\ge 1,  m\ge 2n \} \\ 
L_2 &= \{(ab)^n a^k (ba)^n \mid k<3\}
\end{align}

For $L_2$ my approach was:

> Let us be given a number $p$. Let $z = (ab)^p a^k (ba)^p$, which satisfies $|z| = 2p > p$, and let $z = uvw$ be its decomposition satisfying $|uv| \leq p$ and $|v| > 0$. This means that $v = (ab)^j$ for some $0 \le j \le p$. We choose $i = 2$ for $uv^iw$, which equals $(ab)^{p+j} a^k (ba)^p$. This word has more $ab$ than $ba$, which means that it doesn't belong to the language. Therefore $L_2$ is not regular.

Mainly I am actually confused with the $(ab)^n$, we should decomposed it so that we can pump $v$, but it is necessary to consider different cases of $v$, or is this sufficient?

Comment: I think you have the right general idea here, but I suggest thinking about a few things. First, what is the length of z? Are you sure you calculated it correctly? Second, are you sure about your assertion that $v=(ab)^j$? I think you have a few more cases to consider, but you’re definitely on the right track!

Comment: @awillia91 firstly thanks for the reply! I think the length may be wrong, but the idea was the length of this word is larger than the number of states p and with the condition |uv|<=p, v is probably a composition of a's and b's. Do you have an idea which cases it could possibly be?

Comment: Right, you definitely have the right idea! And the specific length is not that important, as long as it’s greater than the pumping length, but since you wrote it I suggest either giving the exact length or asserting that it’s greater than the pumping length by an argument like $\lvert z \rvert > \lvert (ab)^p \rvert = 2p >p $. Now v could be one character (e.g, $v=b$) or a sequence of characters, and different values of $k$ might lead to different approaches as well. It’s relatively easy to rule out v being one letter. But in your example what if $k=1$? Is it obvious that $z$ is not in $L_2$?

Comment: @awillia91 you are right! So I need to consider v can be either a or b, then it is important that the length of v, if it is odd than it definitely contradict the language form when you pump v. In case |v| is even, when pumping for example i = 2, i is at least p+1, which contradict the language. thanks I did not consider a^k, which needs to be considered as well!

Comment: I think you will also want to pick a specific value for $k$,I suggest $0$ or $2$. I think $k=1$ will give you some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose, for concreteness, that $p = 3$.

You choose the word $z = (ab)^3a^k(ba)^3$. How does this word look like? It is impossible to tell, since we don't know what the value of $k$ is. Let's therefore take $k = 3$, that is, we are looking at the word $z = (ab)^3(ba)^3 = abababbababa$.

Next, we are given a decomposition $abababbababa = uvw$, where $|uv| \leq 3$ and $v \neq \epsilon$. There are six possibilities:

1. $u = \epsilon$, $v = a$, $w = bababbababa$.
2. $u = \epsilon$, $v = ab$, $w = ababbababa$.
3. $u = \epsilon$, $v = aba$, $w = babbababa$.
4. $u = a$, $v = b$, $w = ababbababa$.
5. $u = a$, $v = ba$, $w = babbababa$.
6. $u = ab$, $v = a$, $w = babbababa$.

You need to be able to handle *all* of them. There are four different cases: $v \in (ab)^*$, $v \in (ba)^*$, $v \in a(ba)^*$, $v \in b(ab)^*$. For each of them, you need to find a value of $i$ so that $uv^iw \notin L_2$. When showing that $uv^iw \notin L_2$, you have to show that there are no $n \geq 0$ and $k < 3$ such that $uv^iw = (ab)^n a^k (ba)^n$.